# Fix JobId in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

Is there anyway to fix the job id in Apache Flink within local execution environment from Java?

Kind regards. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no mechanism for setting the job id.